# Implementing the Ask Pattern on the Recipient-Side in Akka-Java Land

Tags: java, asynchronous, akka, actor, future

Every Akka tutorial and its grandmother proudly displays snippets of code, like the one below, showing off how to perform an asynchronous, non-blocking `ask` via Akka Futures:

```
// Groovy pseudo code
class Fizz extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef buzz

    Fizz(ActorRef buzz) {
        super()

        this.buzz = buzz
    }

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof DoSomething) {
            DoSomething ds = message as DoSomething
            Foo foo = doSomething(ds)
            Future<BuzzResult> buzzFut = buzz.ask(new ProcessResult(foo))

            buzzFut.onSuccess(new BuzzResultHandler(), system.dispatcher)
        }
    }

    Foo doSomething(DoSomething ds) { … }
}
```

But nowhere can I actually find a code snippet that shows how to **service this `ask` on the other (recipient) side**. Okay, so `Fizz` has `ask`ed `Buzz` with a `ProcessResult` message, and has set up an `onSuccess` handler to capture the result once `Buzz` sends it back. **But how does `Buzz` actually send it back?!?**

`Buzz` is an actor, and so it does all its messaging through `onReceive`:

```
class Buzz extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof ProcessResult) {
            ProcessResult pr = message as ProcessResult

            BuzzResult br = BuzzResultFactory.createBuzzResult(pr)

            // Oh snap, I can’t send ‘br’ back to the Fizz’s BuzzResultHandler 
            // because I return void…
        }
    }
}
```

If `onReceive` returns `void`, **how can it ever possibly return a result when `ask`ed something by `Fizz` (or any other actor)?!?**

Of course I welcome and am *enormously* appreciative of any answers, even in Scala, but would ask for any code snippets to be in Java since Scala looks like hieroglyphics to me.

Comment: Why the downvote sans explanation? That's called a hit-and-run in some places. This question is unique, answerable, shows research, and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Unhand me you fiend!

Comment: To those of you that like to hit and run: before you downvote this, please have the courage to accept this dare: Please find me the exact place in the Akka documentation that explains how `ask` requests back to `sender` are automatically mapped back to the `Future` defined in the asking (calling) actor? **This is not explained anywhere in the documentation.** So please think twice before downloading this. If you ask me, this question should be added to the Akka docs, not shunned and downvoted.

Comment: And, if the person who keeps downvoting this is Baxter, then at least have the courage to speak. Bark twice if you're in Milwaukee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple actually.

You just reply to the sender:

```
sender().tell(yourResponse)
```

Since you are using the ask-Pattern, this response will not be received by the actual initiator of the ask, but by the onSuccessHandler.